# Django app has a no ImportError: No module named 'django.core.context_processors'

Tags: python, django, git, heroku, deployment

Tried git pushing my app after tweaking it and got the following error.

```
ImportError: No module named 'django.core.context_processors'
```

this was not showing up in my heroku logs and my app works locally so I was confused. I had to set debug to true on the production side to finally figure this out. What can I do to clear this up?

this is some of the traceback

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://hispanicheights.com/
Django Version: 1.10.1
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named 'django.core.context_processors'
Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py in import_module, line 126
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 3.5.1
Python Path:['/app',
             '/app/.heroku/python/bin',
             '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools-23.1.0-py3.5.egg',
             '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py3.5.egg',
             '/app',
             '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python35.zip',
             '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5',
             '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/plat-linux',
             '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
             '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages',
             '/app',
             '/app']
```

I looked at line 126 and this is what's there

```
 return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
```

this

```
django.core.context_processors
```

is no where to be found in the init file. I looked in my settings file for production and saw this

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'debug': True,
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                "django.core.context_processors.request",
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

am I supposed to modify this some how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing `"django.core.context_processors.request"` from your settings.

In Django 1.10 `django.core.context_processors` has been moved to `django.template.context_processors`. See [the release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.8/#django-core-context-processors)

You already have the request context processors, no need to add it again with the wrong location.

Comment: Thanks I solved it while you were responding. but thanks. how does it work locally. and my site was working just the day before. weird.

Comment: My guess is that you used an older version of Django locally?

Comment: it's the same one. locally I just run ./manage.py runserver and test it and git push my tweaks. they are both 1.10. but I will delete what you said, just realized the other one was there after you said it. From what I've read people have this after they pip install some package. thanks for responding though.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, in settings.py In my TEMPLATES, I changed this line from this

```
django.core.context_processors.request
```

to this

```
django.template.context_processors.request
```

and now I can see my site. I hope this helps someone.